# How to clone old builder to make a new builder object?

Tags: java, clone, builder, builder-pattern

I have a builder class which I am using in one of my project.

- Let's say I have `metricA` as builder based on below  class.
- I need to make a new builder `metricB` based on `metricA` by cloning `metricA` so that `metricB` contains all the values which were already there in `metricA`.

In the constructor of `MetricHolder` I am initializing some fields (which are not set directly) basis on fields that have been set already.

- `clientTypeOrPayId` - I am initializing this field. If `payId` is  present, then I will set this value or I will set `clientType`.
- `clientKey` - I am initializing this field as well in the same constructor.
- And most importantly, I am putting few mandatory fields in the `clientPayload` map. I am not sure what is the right way to do that. But I need to add `is_clientid` and `is_deviceid` into the map. (In general I am adding few more fields).
- And then in the last of the constructor, I am calculating latency difference and sending it to some other system.

Below is my class:

```
public final class MetricHolder {
  private final String clientId;
  private final String deviceId;
  private final String payId;
  private final String clientType;
  private final String clientTypeOrPayId;
  private final Schema schema;
  private final String schemaId;
  private final String clientKey;
  private final Map<String, String> clientPayload;
  private final Record record;
  private final long clientCreateTimestamp;
  private final long clientSentTimestamp;

  private MetricHolder(Builder builder) {
    this.payId = builder.payId;
    this.siteId = builder.siteId;
    this.clientType = builder.clientType;
    this.clientId = builder.clientId;
    this.deviceId = builder.deviceId;
    this.schema = builder.schema;
    this.schemaId = builder.schemaId;
    // populating all the required fields in the map and make it immutable
    // not sure whether this is right?
    builder.clientPayload.put("is_clientid", (clientId == null) ? "false" : "true");
    builder.clientPayload.put("is_deviceid", (clientId == null) ? "true" : "false");
    this.clientPayload = Collections.unmodifiableMap(builder.clientPayload);
    this.clientTypeOrPayId = Strings.isNullOrEmpty(payId) ? clientType : payId;
    this.record = builder.record;
    this.clientKey = "process:" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ":"
                        + ((clientId == null) ? deviceId : clientId);
    this.clientCreateTimestamp = builder.clientCreateTimestamp;
    this.clientSentTimestamp = builder.clientSentTimestamp;
    // this will be called twice while cloning
    // what is the right way to do this then?
    SendData.getInstance().insert(clientTypeOrPayId,
        System.currentTimeMillis() - clientCreateTimestamp);
    SendData.getInstance().insert(clientTypeOrPayId,
        System.currentTimeMillis() - clientSentTimestamp);
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private final Record record;
    private Schema schema;
    private String schemaId;
    private String clientId;
    private String deviceId;
    private String payId;
    private String clientType;
    private Map<String, String> clientPayload;
    private long clientCreateTimestamp;
    private long clientSentTimestamp;

    // this is for cloning
    public Builder(MetricHolder packet) {
      this.record = packet.record;
      this.schema = packet.schema;
      this.schemaId = packet.schemaId;
      this.clientId = packet.clientId;
      this.deviceId = packet.deviceId;
      this.payId = packet.payId;
      this.clientType = packet.clientType;
      // make a new map and check whether mandatory fields are present already or not
      // and if they are present don't add it again.
      this.clientPayload = new HashMap<>();
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : packet.clientPayload.entrySet()) {
        if (!("is_clientid".equals(entry.getKey()) || "is_deviceid".equals(entry.getKey())) {
          this.clientPayload.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
      }
      this.clientCreateTimestamp = packet.clientCreateTimestamp;
      this.clientSentTimestamp = packet.clientSentTimestamp;
    }

    public Builder(Record record) {
      this.record = record;
    }

    public Builder setSchema(Schema schema) {
      this.schema = schema;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setSchemaId(String schemaId) {
      this.schemaId = schemaId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
      this.deviceId = deviceId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setPayId(String payId) {
      this.payId = payId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientType(String clientType) {
      this.clientType = clientType;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientPayload(Map<String, String> payload) {
      this.clientPayload = payload;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientCreateTimestamp(long clientCreateTimestamp) {
      this.clientCreateTimestamp = clientCreateTimestamp;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientSentTimestamp(long clientSentTimestamp) {
      this.clientSentTimestamp = clientSentTimestamp;
      return this;
    }

    public MetricHolder build() {
      return new MetricHolder(this);
    }
  }

    // getters
}
```

**Question:-**

Below is how I make `metricA` builder object:

```
MetricHolder metricA = new MetricHolder.Builder(record).setClientId("123456").setDeviceId("abcdefhg")
                .           setPayId("98765").setClientPayload(payloadMapHolder).setClientCreateTimestamp(createTimestamp)
                            .setClientSentTimestamp(sentTimestamp).build();
```

Now this is how I clone the `metricA` object later on in the code when I get all other fields as shown below:

```
MetricHolder metricB = new MetricHolder.Builder(metricA).setSchema(schema).setSchemaId("345").build();
```

I see two problem now:

- First of all, my `SendData.getInstance()` line in the `MetricHolder` constructor will be called twice. First is when I make `metricA` and second when I make `metricB` by cloning `metricA`. But I just want to call it **only once** when I try to create `metricA` builder object? How can I make this possible?
- Second is, the way I am populating `clientPayload` map with two mandatory fields in the `MetricHolder` constructor doesn't look right to me. Is there any other better way to do the same thing?

I guess the whole problem is happening because the way I am cloning `metricA` to make a `metricB` builder object? What is the best way to do this? I want to achieve above two things but in a right way.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear because there is a lot of unnecessary stuff in it (lots of fields and setters etc that don't look relevant). Please can you strip it down to a [mcve], so that the key parts of your code are more apparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I just want to call it only once when I try to create metricA builder object? How can I make this possible?

The most straightforward way is to have a flag in the builder indicating whether it was created by `Record` or by cloning:

```
class Builder {
  final boolean cloned;

  Builder(MetricHolder packet) {
    this.cloned = true;
    // ...
  }

  Builder(Record record) {
    this.cloned = false;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, in the constructor of `MetricHolder`:

```
if (!builder.cloned) {
  SendData.getInstance().whatever();
}
```

But it's worth pointing out that making this call to `SendData` is an example of [doing too much work in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). You should think carefully about whether you really want to be making this call in the constructor, or whether you can factor that out into another method.

> Second is, the way I am populating clientPayload map with two mandatory fields in the MetricHolder constructor doesn't look right to me. Is there any other better way to do the same thing?

You've misunderstood the "unmodifiable" bit of using `Collections.unmodifiableMap`: it's only an unmodifiable *view* of the map parameter; you can still modify the underlying map.

Here's a JUnit test to demonstrate:

```
Map<String, String> original = new HashMap<>();
original.put("hello", "world");

// Obviously false, we just put something into it.
assertFalse(original.isEmpty());

Map<String, String> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableMap(original);
// We didn't modify the original, so we don't expect this to have changed.
assertFalse(original.isEmpty());
// We expect this to be the same as for the original.
assertFalse(unmodifiable.isEmpty());

try {
  unmodifiable.clear();
  fail("Expected this to fail, as it's unmodifiable");
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException expected) {}

// Yep, still the same contents.
assertFalse(original.isEmpty());
assertFalse(unmodifiable.isEmpty());

// But here's where it gets sticky - no exception is thrown.
original.clear();
// Yep, we expect this...
assertTrue(original.isEmpty());

// But - uh-oh - the unmodifiable map has changed!
assertTrue(unmodifiable.isEmpty());
```

The thing is that the map is only unmodifiable if there is no other reference to it hanging around: if you don't have a reference to `original`, `unmodifiable` actually is unmodifiable; otherwise, you can't rely upon the map never changing.

In your particular case, you are simply wrapping the `clientPayload` map in your unmodifiable collection. So, you're overwrite values for previously-constructed instances.

For example:

```
MetricHolder.Builder builder = new MetricHolder.Builder();
MetricHolder first = builder.build();
assertEquals("false", first.clientPayload.get("is_clientid"));
assertEquals("true", first.clientPayload.get("is_deviceid"));

builder.setClientId("").build();
// Hmm, first has changed.
assertEquals("true", first.clientPayload.get("is_clientid"));
assertEquals("false", first.clientPayload.get("is_deviceid"));
```

The correct approach is not to wrap `builder.clientPayload`. Take a copy of the map, modify it, and then wrap with `unmodifiableMap`:

```
{
  Map<String, String> copyOfClientPayload = new HashMap<>(builder.clientPayload);
  copyOfClientPayload.put("is_clientid", (clientId == null) ? "false" : "true");
  copyOfClientPayload.put("is_deviceid", (clientId == null) ? "true" : "false");
  this.clientPayload = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copyOfClientPayload);
}
```

The surrounding `{}` aren't strictly necessary, but they restrict the scope of `copyOfClientPayload`, so you can't accidentally reuse it later in the constructor.